# Handling multiple transitions between activity and fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-transitions, fragment-backstack

I have 2 fragments in an activity A, Frg1 and Frg2. Frg1 requires an object o1 as input and Frg2 requires o2 as input.

There is another activity B.
So i start from Frg1 where I already have o1. So i populate Frg1 then i move to Frg2 where I get o2 and populate it. 
So in my fragment stack there are Frg1 and Frg2. then from Frg2 i move to activity B thus destroying activity A. So i loose o1 and o2 as well.
On pressing back from activity B, I need to go to Frg2 then on back again I have to go to Frg1.
To solve this I am passing o1 and o2 to activity B and on pressing back retrieving them on activity A.
I want to know if this is the best way or is there any simple way to deal with this.

Comment: are initializing objects in `Activity A`?

Comment: i fetch input objects from rest api calls.

Comment: make their scope global and check if they are null before API call. hopefully they won't destroy when you will back to your activity A.

Comment: use addToBackStack() to retain previous fragment. I have tested your scenario in one of my project it work fine I can navigate from ActivityB to Frag2 to frag1 on pressing back object are retained no use to do any work around

Comment: Thank you guys.... i tried using bundle to retain objects while switching activities..... but i have around 16 activities and they all contain minimum 2 fragments.... so its taking a lot of time to save their states and all.... thanks again.